# Django debug: how to know which template is in use for a specific URL?

Tags: django, debugging

How can I know which template is in use for a specific URL when debugging? For example, what is the template that was used when visiting `/login`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way is to probably install the [Django Debug Toolbar](http://django-debug-toolbar.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) and enable the [template panel](http://django-debug-toolbar.readthedocs.io/en/stable/panels.html#template), which will tell you what templates are used and the available context.

There is also a [template timings](http://django-debug-toolbar.readthedocs.io/en/stable/panels.html#template-timings) panel which lets you assess rendering times for your templates.